# Problem with jQuery .load method and newlines in internet Explorer

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer

I'm trying to load plaintext data using jQuery's load method. This plaintext includes line breaks. I load this data into an HTML <pre> tag.

It works fine in all browsers I tried (Firefox/Linux, [Firefox,Chrome,Opera]/Windows) except for Internet Explorer, where the line breaks from the original file are removed. I've tried to save the file with either Windows line-breaks and Linux line-breaks, but this makes no difference with respect to browser behavior (neither IE, which continues to misbehave, nor the others, which keep behaving).

This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="data">
    <pre></pre>
</div>
```

This is the jQuery call:

```
$(function(){
    $("#data pre").load("lorem.txt");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

... or you can replace the text if the browser is IE:

```
$("#data pre").load("lorem.txt", function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status != "error") {
    if (($.browser.msie)&&(jQuery.browser.version=="8.0"))
        $("#data pre").html(response.replace(/\r\n/g, "<br>"));
    }
});
```

Comment: Nice. It doesn't replace consecutive linebreaks though, i.e. what in other browsers displays as a line break plus a blank line shows now as a single break, no blank line (at least in IE7).

Comment: You can replace my regular expression with a more complex one /g means global matching. I can't test in IE7 cause I don't have it. I've compared the result in IE8,Opera,FF,Chrome,Safari and the result are all the same.

Comment: Well in fact the replacement does work, it just seems that IE7 ignores consecutive <br>s within a <pre> tag. It looks fine on IE8.